# Invalid mfc message map being generated

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I have a simple test application in MFC, but it does not work. The message handlers simply don't get called. The window receives the messages, but does not invoke handlers registered in message map.

It is a standard mfc single dialog application that has a huge block of buttons and does various calls to the library on pushing them. But it does not call the handlers.

I've traced it and the message map seems to be corrupted. There is standard declaration like:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CommLib_test_x86Dlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedCancel)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON4, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedButton4)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON5, &CommLib_test_x86Dlg::OnBnClickedButton5)
    // many more buttons, but I commented the rest out for test
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And if I put a breakpoint on the first `ON_WM_`* (i.e. into the `GetThisMessageMap` static method) and look at the content of the message map, the first entry is correct, but the rest is mostly 0 *and* the array size does not correspond to the actual definition. Debugger reports the value as

```
[0] {nMessage=274 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[1] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[2] {nMessage=0 nCode=19 nID=4206192 ...}
[3] {nMessage=55 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[4] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[5] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[6] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[7] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[8] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[9] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[10] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[11] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[12] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[13] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[14] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
[15] {nMessage=0 nCode=0 nID=0 ...}
```

The code compiles fine with no warning or anything.

It is important to note that the application is part of huge collection of projects and that those projects share compiler options. We actually generate the visual studio project, but before we used the `.vsprops` files. I didn't use the project for some time and it's conceivable that the compiler flags have changed meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it. The compiler flags did indeed change. The dreaded `/vmg` flag got added (we use it in some other library and it propagated to incorrect project during refactoring). This flag is incompatible with MFC, because it changes definition of the message map item.

Long story: In an attempt to save some space, Microsoft decided that pointers to members will be represented differently depending on whether the class uses single, multiple or virtual inheritance. While it looks fine in theory, in practice it has problems when:

- pointers to members of incomplete types are declared (which is legal in C++).

I suspect it also causes problems when:

- pointers to members of class with more complicated pointers needs to be cast to pointer to members of a base class with simpler pointers.

The documentation does not mention that case, but it's kind of obvious. It's by the way exactly what MFC does.

The specification (ISO/IEC 14882-2011) only requires `static_cast` to pointer to member of base if the base is  not inherited virtually, but in Microsoft compiler it does not work even if the base class only has linear inheritance, but the subclass has multiple inheritance and the base is non-first. Well, everybody knows the compiler is non-conforming already.